# List< > Inside of Dictionary< K,List< > > (C#)

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Student here.

Working on a current C# project. I have to create a List< Card > of playing cards, and a Dictionary< string,List< Card > >.

List gets created independently, and the dictionary holds collections of cards. Cards can be added or removed from collections.

I'm having trouble adding a card to a collection though. I've gotten the index number of the list from user input, and am trying to simply update the value in the dictionary based on the index.

The line that is throwing an error is here. The error is 
Cannot implicitly convert type '< filename.CardClass >' to
System.Collections.Generic.List< filename.CardClass >'

I for the life of me can't figure out what that means and how to resolve it..

```
_collections[input] = _cards[cardSelectionIndex];
```

Here is my current code block:

```
    public void AddToCollection()
    {
        PrintValuesCollections<string, List<Card>>(_collections);
        Console.WriteLine("Type in the name of the collection to add a card to:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        bool found = _collections.ContainsKey(input);
        if (found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List of current cards to choose from:");

            for (int i = 0; i < _cards.Count; i++)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Index number:\r\n"+i+"Card Info:\r\n"+_cards[i]+"\n");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Type in the index of the card from the list to add to the collection:");
            string cardSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            int cardSelectionIndex = 0;
            while (!int.TryParse(cardSelection, out cardSelectionIndex))
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter a number from the list above: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            _collections[input] = _cards[cardSelectionIndex];
            _cards.RemoveAt(cardSelectionIndex);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Collection name not found.");
    }
```

Comment: `_collections[input].Add(_cards[cardSelectionIndex]);`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but wouldn't this add a new unique key? I should of mentioned before, I have keys that are already created, and simply want to update the value based on a key input from a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `_collections` is type `Dictionary<string, List<Card>>` and `_cards` is a `List<Card>`

So this is what you're trying to do:

```
//_collections[input] = _cards[cardSelectionIndex];
List<Card> a = _collections[input];
Card b = _cards[cardSelectionIndex];
a = b;
```

Notice that the types of `a` and `b`. This correctly gives the error: "`Cannot implicitly convert type '< filename.CardClass >' to System.Collections.Generic.List< filename.CardClass >'`"

What you probably want to do is add a card to that list

```
List<Card> a = _collections[input];
Card b = _cards[cardSelectionIndex];
a.Add(b);
```

or simply

```
_collections[input].Add(_cards[cardSelectionIndex]);
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation flakes!

So I don't have to open another thread, I do have to print a list based off the key of a user input. I'm currently using 

for (int i = 0; i < _collections.Keys(input).Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Index number:\r\n" + i + "Card Info:\r\n" + _cards[i] + "\n");
                }

But it's giving me non-invocable member 'Dictionary< string,List < Card > >.keys cannot be used like a method. 

Any ideas here?

Comment: @DylanColeDuke no problem! Enjoy the rest of your Sunday :)

Comment: If you want to print the `_cards` list, then you should use that list in the `for` loop. `for(int i = 0; i < _cards.Count; i++) ...`

Comment: Close, but I don't need the _cards list. I need to print the list from a dictionary key.

Comment: @DylanColeDuke take a look here: https://gist.github.com/cal-pratt/bc43b2ea4933d37f6a1f29275e9ecebc

Comment: Fantastic, I see what you did there in declaring an independent list before hand, I was trying to do too many steps at once. Thanks for your help flakes, hope you have a good rest of your Sunday too!

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain your exception a little bit more pictorial.

You are creating a `Dictionary<string,List<Card>>` which is nothing else then a List of `KeyValuePair<string,List<Card>>` accessed by the **unique Key**. This means every entry in your Dictionary is a List of cards indexed by the key of type string.

For example:

```
Key | Value
"hearts" | List<Card> {1, 2, 7, 8, Queen}
"spades" | List<Card> {King, Ace}
```

Now what your exception is saying you, that you try to override a deck of cards with just a single card.

This is what you do:

```
List<Card> spades = collection["spades"]; // King, Ace
spades = new Card(Queen); // Your Exception
```

but this is what you may want to do:

```
List<Card> spades = collection["spades"]; // King, Ace
spades.Add( Card(Queen) ); // Add an element to the List
```

Now your dictionary looks like this:

```
Key | Value
"hearts" | List<Card> {1, 2, 7, 8, Queen}
"spades" | List<Card> {King, Ace, Queen}
```

And if you want to add a deck of "clubs" to your collection you can call:

```
collection.Add( "clubs", new List<Card> {1, 2, 3, Ace} );
```

or short:

```
collection["clubs"] = new List<Card> {1, 2, 3, Ace};
```

But be carefull the first one can raise a duplic key exception if the key is already in the dictionary and the second one will just create a new entry if it is not existing or overrides the existing one.

Comment: Great post! In case **unique key** is not clear to all... it is important to note that all dictionaries can be represented by key-value-pair lists, but not all key-value-pair lists can be dictionaries. Dictionaries require one unique or zero correspondences from domain to range. `key->value`. A normal key-value-pair lists can have multiple correspondences per domain value. Keys in this case are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @flakes you are absolutely right. Thanks for the input.